# Unspecified error in JavaEdit.Set

Tags: automation, qtp

I have few issues working with QTP:

•         I am setting 100 value to using a JavaEdit box.
•         I have added the objects to the objects repository using object spy.
•         I get an error “ Unspecified error” when I run my action and it takes more time to give this error.

Comment: As QTP taking more time to display error message, their are chances of smart identification.Is there any other JavaEdit box present on screen
?

Comment: @4M01 Thank you for the reply.Yes there is another JavaEdit box on the screen.But how do i solve the issue?!

Comment: when you highlight JavaEdit box added in OR,does it showing correct object?

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaEdit.Type instead.

The difference between the two are that JavaEdit.set clears the edit box and sets the edit box to the value whereas JavaEdidt.type types each character into the edit box.
The only problem would be if the edit box already contains text but that may not be a problem for your test.

Also make sure you have the correct details in the Object Repository.